# Arranging numbers so that $i$ is not immediately followed by $i+1$

Tags: combinatorics

How many arrangements of the integers $1,2,\ldots,n$ are such that no number $i$ is ever immediately followed by $i+1$?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  What have you tried?  Where did this problem come from?

Comment: The other question doesn't allow $i+1$ followed by $i$ either.

Comment: False duplicate: $A000255\neq A002464$. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is sequence 255 from the Online Encyclopaedia of Integer Sequences
https://oeis.org/A000255